# Is it normal the Trader ask money to withdraw the profits

Tags: fraud, trust-wallet

The investor asking $2000 dollars fee to withdraw my profits.When I refused to pay them from couple of days then they said other way to withdraw is via Trust Wallet. Trader asked to download the app & send them the screenshot.I really don’t have any idea on this and how I can withdraw my investments. How to deal with this senario. Please help how to proceed and withdraw.

Thanks

Comment: What is Trust Wallet? Did "investor"/"Trader" gave you a link to it?

Comment: No, asked to download from App.

Comment: I am certain you are being scammed. The profits are fictional. There is no way to get back any money you invested. Any attempt to get your money back will just lose more money. Report the "investor" to your local police.